# Google o auth login SSL error

Tags: php, google-api, google-signin

Since today my Google oauth login for my php application suddenly stopped working.

I get the following error:

> stream_socket_client(): Peer certificate CN=`*.storage.googleapis.com'
>   did not match expected CN=`www.googleapis.com' stream_socket_client():
>   Failed to enable crypto stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to
>   ssl://www.googleapis.com:443 (Unknown error)

I'm using this endpoint: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo.

Comment: I have this problem as well, `file_get_contents(): Peer certificate CN='*.storage.googleapis.com' did not match expected CN='maps.googleapis.com'`

Comment: Are you using a specific PHP framework such as CakePHP or Zend etc?

Comment: I get this exact error, using CakePHP's `CakeSocket`.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue with CakePHP using the HTTP Socket.

Likely this could be happening if using a framework, or HTTP Socket Library.

The fix in CakePHP, was to disable the ssl_verify_host

According to the documentation:
"Set to false if you wish to ignore hostname match errors when validating certificates."
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/httpsocket.html

e.g.

```
$this->HttpSocket = new HttpSocket(array(
            'ssl_verify_host' => false
        ));
```

This solved the issue for me.  I suspect in other frameworks, there would be a similar option, and this should solve it!

Comment: This will do the trick until I have a day to upgrade my server! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For me, my version of SSL (libssl I think) was out of date and wasn't recognizing the certificate's Alternative Common Names.

I ran the following commands:

```
$ apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
$ apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Be warned that upgrading (especially dist-upgrade) could cause problems with your system.

Comment: tried apt-get update && apt-get upgrade (debian 7), but this isn't working.

Comment: Check for uninstalled packages due to dependency issues. (I think `apt-get upgrade` again). You might have to do a dist-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there was a change to the certificate that requires SAN support - which was added in PHP 5.6 http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Transport-Layer-Security-%28HTTPS-SSL-and-TLS%29.html.

If you can't upgrade to that version, try switching to the `Google_IO_Curl transport rather than streams, and that should work fine.

```
$client->setIo(new Google_IO_Curl($client));
```

Comment: I am on 5.5 so I will upgrade soon but if you need a quick temporary fix, turning off the SSL verification as described in MichaelHoughton's post worked great.